# I can not show the images of a view

Tags: image, cakephp-3.0

I have a problem with the path of the images, if I load a view in `/` show the images without problems that are in `webroot/imagenes/` but if I access the view directly with `/vista/vista` then I change the path of the images `webroot/vista/imagenes/` and of course, since it is not the correct route, it does not show them.

How do I solve this?

Comment: how about url helper?

Comment: How do I call the images?

For example

`<img src='imagenes/escudof.jpg' alt="Coat of arms">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add leading slash to url eg.
`/imagenes/escudof.jpg`

Comment: looks like we posted in the same time

Answer (score 0):

oohh I found the problem, I put it in front ../ and the problem was solved:

```
<img src='../imagenes/escudof.jpg' alt="Escudo">
```

regards